# Seeking and deleting elements in lists of a parsed file and saving result to another file

Tags: python, c, parsing, txt

I have a large .txt file that is a result of a C-file being parsed containing various blocks of data, but about 90% of them are useless to me. I'm trying to get rid of them and then save the result to another file, but have hard time doing so. At first I tried to delete all useless information in unparsed file, but then it won't parse. My .txt file is built like this:

//Update: Files I'm trying to work on comes from pycparser module, that I found on a GitHub.

File before being parsed looks like this:

[image]

And after using pycparser

```
file_to_parse = pycparser.parse_file(current_directory + r"\D_Out_Clean\file.d_prec")
```

[image]

I want to delete all blocks that starts with word *Typedef*. This module stores this in an one big list that I can access via it's attribute.
[image]

Currently my code looks like this:

```
len_of_ext_list = len(file_to_parse.ext)
i = 0
while i < len_of_ext_list:
    if 'TypeDecl' not in file_to_parse.ext[i]:
        print("NOT A TYPEDECL")
        print(file_to_parse.ext[i], type(file_to_parse.ext[i]))
        parsed_file_2 = open(current_directory + r"\Zadanie\D_Out_Clean_Parsed\clean_file.d_prec", "w+")
        parsed_file_2.write("%s%s\n" %("", file_to_parse.ext[i]))
        parsed_file_2.close
        #file_to_parse_2 = file_to_parse.ext[i]
    i+=1
```

But above code only saves one last *FuncDef* from a unparsed file, and I don't know how to change it.
So, now I'm trying to get rid of all typedefs in parsed file as they don't have any valuable information for me. I want to now what functions definitions and declarations are in file, and what type of global variables are stored in parsed file. Hope this is more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading the entire input file into a string, and then doing a regex replacement:

```py
with open(current_directory + r"\D_Out\file.txt", "r+") as file:
    with open(current_directory + r"\D_Out_Clean\clean_file.txt", "w+") as output:
        data = file.read()
        data = re.sub(r'type(?:\n\{.*?\}|[^;]*?;)\n?', '', data, flags=re.S)
        output.write(line)
```

Here is a regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lWHVkB/1) showing that the replacement logic is working.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen for an answer. It works ok, as it deletes almost the content. But I have a follow up questions. Sometimes there is something after the **}** i.e.

{
uint16 n;
uint16 k;
}std_VersionType

And right now this line is left untouched. What should be added to delete it?

Comment: I can only reply to you by seeing the real data.  If you want me to edit my answer, then update your question.

Comment: Ok, I updated my question with all the details. I'm sorry if at first it was not clear, as english is not my first language and I was in a rush.